# VB.NET, Append to CSV results with incorrect output

Tags: vb.net, csv, output, streamwriter

I'm writing a little log program to log specific groups where me and a friend are in.

I managed it to create a CSV file where the first line will be written out with six columns successfully.

Now that this happened, the file has been created with this six columns, the next step is to add a line which logs these six properties.

However, whenever this happens, the only thing that will be logged is the date, which is the first item in the log.

This is the procedure of logging a message:

```
'And for each new entry, text will send to file here.
            Dim outFile As IO.StreamWriter = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(csvFilePath, True)
            outFile.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"), uTime, currentPlayer, Telegram.bot.from_ID, Telegram.bot.message_id, Telegram.bot.message_text)
            outFile.Close()
```

The properties are Date, Timestamp, Player, PlayerID, MessageID and RPmessage, in that order.
However like I said only the date appears and all other 5 items just don't appear.
What have I done wrong here? I checked this line multiple times, however I could not find anything that could be wring in my eyes. Visual Studio also doesn't spit out any errors when this function is being called.

Comment: If you're using VS2015 or later you could use `outFile.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") & $", {uTime},{currentPlayer},{Telegram.bot.from_ID},{Telegram.bot.message_id},{Telegram.bot.message_text}")`. Or look up String.Format. Or just concatenate the strings with `&`. What you have done is pass several parameters to `WriteLine` when you meant to pass one string.

Comment: Check the parameters for `WriteLine`.  What you are passing is not one of the options.

Comment: Alright, I saw my mistake here (@Brian). Thank you for the hint.

Also, I'm using the 2012 version (for various reasons actually). (@Andrew)


How could I solve my problem with this much information?

Comment: @AndrewMorton - Why convert the `DateTime` to string and then concatenate to an interpolated string?  Why not include the date time in the interpolated string as well?  Ex:  $"{DateTime.Now:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss}, {uTime}, {currentPlayer}.....", etc.  Just curious if you had a specific reason.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway 1) I may not have had VS open to make sure I got the syntax right and 2) I didn't actually know at the time that you could put the format in like that :)

Answer (score 0):

Keeping with your approach, you simply need to add a format string at the beginning.

```
outFile.WriteLine("{0,-20}{1,-20}{2,-20}{3,-20}{4,-20}{5,-20}", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

This format string will create 6 columns of data that are left-aligned in a 20 character field.  Obviously you need to adjust the numbers for your situation.

Comment: I prefer to use TAB instead of space. it is less common and easier the keep to field separated. You don't have to worry on the size of column.

Comment: Then look into one of the options from @Andrew.  The last one might be good in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I worked a little around and fixed it so far.
It's not pretty, but I wrote the output with & character and added a comma to each result before adding the & character, which looks like this:

```
                outFile.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss, ") & unix + ", " & currentPlayer + ", " & Telegram.bot.from_ID + "," & Telegram.bot.message_id + ", " & Telegram.bot.message_text)
```

It's not pretty, however it works, as long every item is a string.

Comment: You should use `&` to concatenate things into a string, not `+`. Also, as CSV files are normally meant to be read by a computer it is usual to *not* have spaces after the commas.

Comment: The "+" is there to add a comma to the end of each entry. As example, see the string unix. It contains a timestamp and all I did was to add a comma with +, the next item added with &.